# Lentidão ao buscar dados com ajax e php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um site, onde tenho um sessão de blog, porém quando o sistema está buscando os artigos, demora um pouco a exibir

A estrutura que estou utilizando:

pagina PHP > Ajax Call (jquery utiliza ajax para requisitar dados via POST (resposata json)) > PHP Controller (filtra a função enviada pelo ajax e faz a requisição dos dados para o model) > PHP Model (mysql requisição)

Exemplo da função para exibir os artigos:

Example of function to show blog articles:

```
function buscaTodos(current = 1){
$('.lista_materias').empty();//cleans container of articles
try{
    showLoader();//loader

                $.ajax({  
                    type: 'POST',  
                    url: 'controller/ajax/Artigos.ajax.php', //php controller
                    data: { 
                        'func': "buscaTodos",//php function
                        'current': current
                     },
                    success: function(response) {
                        var res = response.split('[:::]');//parse response of php. Example: 1 to success 0 to error->1[:::]{json response here}

                        if(res[0]==1){//if response is success

                            var obj = JSON.parse(res[1]);//parse json response

                            jQuery.each(obj,function(o, i){
                                //FILL WITH ARTICLES
                                $(".lista_materias").append(
                                    '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="margin-bottom:10px;">'+
                                        '<div class="course-box">'+
                                            '<div class="image-wrap entry">'+
                                                '<img src="images/geral/defer.gif" data-src="images/geral/defer.gif" data-original="images/artigos/'+i['img_box']+'.jpg" data-webp="images/artigos/'+i['img_box']+'.webp" class="imgElastic img-webp" alt="'+i['figcaption']+'" title="'+i['figcaption']+'" class="img-responsive" />'+
                                                '<div class="magnifier">'+
                                                     '<a href="artigos/'+tituloUrl(i['uu'])+'/" title=""><i class="flaticon-add"></i></a>'+
                                                '</div>'+
                                            '</div><!-- end image-wrap -->'+
                                            '<div class="course-details">'+
                                                '<h4>'+
                                                    '<small>Detetive Particular Blog</small>'+
                                                    '<a href="artigos/'+tituloUrl(i['uu'])+'/" title="">'+i['titulo']+'</a>'+
                                                '</h4>'+
                                                '<p class="desc_artigo">'+i['descricao']+'</p>'+
                                            '</div><!-- end details -->'+
                                            '<div class="course-footer clearfix">'+
                                                '<div class="pull-left">'+
                                                    '<ul class="list-inline">'+
                                                        '<li><a href="artigos/'+tituloUrl(i['uu'])+'"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Detetive Particular André</a></li>'+
                                                        '<li><a href="artigos/'+tituloUrl(i['uu'])+'"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> '+converteDataTimeUsToBr(i['data_criacao'])+'</a></li>'+
                                                        //'<li><a href="artigos/'+tituloUrl(o.url)+'"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> '+o.contador+' Views</a></li>'+
                                                    '</ul>'+
                                                '</div><!-- end left -->'+
                                            '</div><!-- end footer -->'+
                                        '</div><!-- end box -->'+
                                    '</div><!-- end col -->'
                                );
                            });
                        }else{
                           //showAlert("Bancos",res[1],2);
                           showAlert("Falha ao consultar", "Ocorreu um erro ao consultar os dados. Atualize a página ou entre contato por telefone. \n <span class='code'></span>", 1,'<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger radius_md" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>');
                        }
                        hideLoader();
                    },complete(){
                        getWebp();
                    }
                });



}catch(erro){
    hideLoader();
    showAlert("Falha ao consultar", "Ocorreu um erro ao consultar os dados. Atualize a página ou entre contato por telefone. \n <span class='code'>"+erro.message+"</span>", 1,'<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger radius_md" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>');
    }

}
```

Artigos.ajax.php

```
<?php
    require_once("../../autoload.php");
    require_once("../../vendor/autoload.php");
    //echo "<pre>".var_export($_POST,true)."</pre>";

    //Controller
    global $controller;
    $controller = new Artigos_controller();

    //DEFINE QUAL Ã‰ A FUNCAO
    $func='';
    if(isset($_POST['func']) && strlen($_POST['func'])>0){
        $func=$_POST['func'];
    }else{
        echo '0[:::]Falha interna ao gerar o formulÃ¡rio.';die;
    }

    switch($func){
        case "buscaTodos":buscaTodos($_POST);break;
        case "buscaTodosConta":buscaTodosConta();break;
        default : echo "0[:::]Falha ao processar";break;
    }

    function buscaTodos($post){

        global $controller;

        $exibe = $controller->todosArtigos($post);

        if($exibe[0]){
            echo "1[:::]".$exibe[1];
        }else{
            echo "0[:::]".$exibe[1];
        }
    }
    function buscaTodosConta(){

        global $controller;

        $exibe = $controller->buscaTodosConta();

        if($exibe[0]){
            echo "1[:::]".$exibe[1];
        }else{
            echo "0[:::]".$exibe[1];
        }
    }


?>
```

Artigos_controller.class.php

```
<?php
class Artigos_controller{

    private $model;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->model = new Artigos_model();
    }

    public function todosArtigos($p){
        $de = (($p['current']-1)*6);
        $materias = $this->model->todosArtigos($de);

        if($materias[0]){
            if(count($materias[1])>0){
                return array(true,json_encode($materias[1]));
            }
        }else{
            return array(false,$materias[1]);
        }

    }
    public function buscaTodosConta(){
        $qtd = $this->model->buscaTodosConta();

        if($qtd[0]){
            if($qtd[1]>0){
                return array(true,$qtd[1]);
            }
        }else{
            return array(false,$qtd[1]);
        }

    }
    public function buscaDetalhe($id){
        $detalhe = $this->model->buscaDetalhe($id);

        if($detalhe[0]){

                return array(true,$detalhe[1]);

        }else{
            return array(false,$detalhe[1]);
        }

    }
    public function getLinks(){
        $links = $this->model->getLinks();

        if($links[0]){
            return $links[1];
        }else{
            return array();
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Artigos_model.class.php

```
<?php

class Artigos_model{

    private $con;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->con = Conn::connect();
    }

    public function todosArtigos($de){
        try{

            if(!$this->con[0]){
                throw new Exception("Falha ao conectar com o banco de dados: ".$this->con[1]);
            }

            $materias = array();

            $query = $this->con[1]->prepare("select id,titulo,descricao,data_criacao,texto,nome_img_box,img_box,figcaption,contador,data_modificado,url as uu from materias order by contador limit $de,6");
            $query->execute();
            $count = $query->rowCount();
           if($count>0){
                $materias = $query->fetchAll();
           }
            return array(true,$materias);

        }catch(Exception $error){
            return array(false,$error->getMessage());
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Já ouviu falar sobre o Axios ? É um cliente HTTP baseado em Promises.
Desde que conheci o Axios nunca mais usei a função Ajax do Jquery. O Axios é muito mais rápido e tem a sintaxe mais simples na minha opinião, vou deixar um exemplo de utilização pra você com o link do Código Fonte do Axios. Segue o exemplo de utilização:

**JavaScript:**

```js
axios.post('exemplo.php', {
    varialvel: valor
}).then(function (response) {
    
    //Resposta do PHP
    var response = response.data;
    console.log(response);
    
}).catch(function (error) { });
```

Como pode ver é muito simples, no código acima eu reescrevi a variável que recebe a resposta do PHP (*response*) para o valor contigo no atributo *data*, pois o *response* vem com outras informações sobre a requisição realizada.

**Código PHP:**

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $body   = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $post   = json_decode($body, true);

    $response = [

        'error'     => false,
        'mensagem'  => $post['variavel']

    ];

    echo json_encode($response);
```

No exemplo acima, você pode reparar que o PHP não vai receber esses dados da mesma forma que recebe quando utilizamos o Ajax com Jquery. Mas não é difícil de compreender o recebimento dessas informações, resumidamente nós estamos "pegando" tudo que o PHP está recebendo do Axios em formato JSON e convertendo em um vetor para a variável *$post*, logo após isso você pode utilizar a variável *$post* como se fosse *$_POST*. Espero que tenha sido útil. Abç amigo !

Segue o link do *Código Fonte* do **Axios**:
[Axios CDN](https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js)

Projeto no **GitHub**:
[Axios GitHub](https://github.com/axios/axios)